# How to concatenate multiple columns where, if column 1 = column 2 then get column 3... in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I want to concatenate multiple columns but eliminate duplicated cells if exist in the next column. I know that coalesce() and isnull() will take care of the null values if exist but how do I take care of duplicates in SQL Server.

This is my `table1`:

| Tier1 | Tier2 | Tier3 | Tier4 | Tier5 | Tier6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Contract | Contract | Contract | Contract | Property | Property |

I want the result to be Contract|Property

```
select 
    isnull(Tier1, '') + '|' + 
    isnull(Tier2, '') + '|' + 
    isnull(Tier3, '') + '|' + 
    isnull(Tier4, '') + '|' + 
    isnull(Tier5, '') + '|' + 
    isnull(Tier6, '') 
from 
    table1
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: i think one of the approach is unpivot the table, eliminate the dups and then pivot/concat

Comment: can you show example data and expected?

Answer (score 3):

Here we unpivot your data and then apply a string_agg() to the distinct values

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Odvmvsa0)**

```
Select B.NewValue
 from  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select NewValue = string_agg(Value,'|')
                From (
                Select distinct Value
                  From ( values (Tier1) 
                               ,(Tier2) 
                               ,(Tier3) 
                               ,(Tier4) 
                               ,(Tier5) 
                               ,(Tier6) 
                          ) B2(Value)
                   )B1
             ) B
```

**If 2016+, Yet another option (less performant than above)**

```
Select B.*
 from  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
               Select NewValue = string_agg(Value,'|')
                From ( Select Distinct Value 
                         From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                         Where [key] like 'Tier%'
                     ) B1
             ) B
```

Answer (score 2):

One more generic solution.

It is working regardless of the number of columns in the table.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Tier1  VARCHAR(20), Tier2  VARCHAR(20),Tier3 VARCHAR(20), Tier4 VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (Tier1, Tier2, Tier3, Tier4) VALUES
('Contract', 'Contract', 'Property', 'Property'),
('Contract', 'Property', 'Contract', 'Property');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , result = STUFF(c.query('
        for $x in distinct-values(/root/*[local-name()!="id"])
        return concat("| ", $x)
    ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| id |  Tier1   |  Tier2   |  Tier3   |  Tier4   |       result        |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Contract | Contract | Property | Property | Contract | Property |
|  2 | Contract | Property | Contract | Property | Contract | Property |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```